# REST API new users not posting to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am new to building REST API's, and I am trying to enter new user information into a collection called 'Users', however, when I submit the information I get `Cannot POST /register`

Below is my code

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express') 
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const expressValidator = require('express-validator')


mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'))

app.use(express.json())

const articlesRouter = require('./routes/articles')
app.use('/articles', articlesRouter)

const userRouter = require('./routes/users')
app.use('/register', userRouter)

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

})

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs')
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))
```

Users model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String, 
    email: String, 
    password: String, 
    permissionLevel: Number, 
    created: Date}, 
    { collection: 'Users'});

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
    var query = {email: email};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    user.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch)
    });
}
```

users routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Users = require('../models/users')
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

//Register Page - GET
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'register'
    });
});

//Login Page - GET
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.hbs', {
        pageTitle: 'login'
    });
});

//Register - POST
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    //validations
    req.checkBody('firstName', 'Your First Name is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lastName', 'Your Last Name is Required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'A valid email is required').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'An Account Passowrd Is Required').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors:errors 
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new newUser({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            password: password,
        });

        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
            if(err) throw(err);
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success_message', "You are now registered!");
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    email: 'email'
},
function(email, password, done){
    Users.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, Users){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!Users){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Email Address'});
        }

        Users.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, ismatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(ismatch){
                return done (null, user); 
            } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Passowrd'});
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Users.getUserByID(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user) 
    });
}); 

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    successFlash: 'Welcome',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid Email or Passowrd!'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('Success_message', 'You are now logged out!')
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router
```

I suspect the conflict is between the router /register and the my 'Users' collection. I'm just unable to pinpoint what the issue could be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your `userRouter` is mounted on `/users` (from your code: `app.use('/users', userRouter)`, meaning that all the routes you declared in the router are prefixed by `/users`).
Try calling `POST /users/register`.

Comment: I'm doing this all local, so i'm entering the user's information at http://localhost:5000/Users. Are you saying I should be using http://localhost:5000/Users/register instead?

Comment: Yup, exactly :)

Comment: What do i need to change if want to post to `http://localhost:5000/register` instead?

Comment: Do not mount the register route on the `userRouter`. You could simply do `app.post('/register', handleRegister)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You're using users routes file at /users route, so when you declare /register route in users routes file it become /users/register please send your REST API request to /users/register endpoint

Comment: I commented this above, but i'll also do it here, because i'm confused. I'm doing this all local, so i'm entering the user's information at localhost:5000/Users. Are you saying I should be using localhost:5000/Users/register instead?